# Not able to update in Nestjs using typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an application I am current working on and all other things are working fine except for one endpoint which is update IsTokenExpired. This holds a boolean which could either be true or false. I have been trying to update this isTokenExpired for some time and it seems to have given up on me. Below is the code list:

**password-reset.service.ts**

```
...
async updateExpiryStatus(
    accessToken: string,
    isExpired: boolean
  ): Promise<any> {
    const expiryStatus = await this.passwordRepository.findOne({
      where: { accessToken },
    });
    const result = await this.passwordRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('password_entity')
      .update(PasswordEntity)
      .set({
        isExpired,
      })
      .where('accessToken = :accessToken', { accessToken })
      .execute();
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log({ expiryStatus, accessToken, isExpired });
    console.log('====================================');
    return result;
  }
...
```

**password-reset.controller.ts**

```
 @Put('updateToken/:accessToken')
  updateExpiryStatus(
    @Param('accessToken') accessToken: string,
    @Body() isExpired: boolean
  ): Promise<string> {
    return this.passwordService.updateExpiryStatus(accessToken, isExpired);
  }
}
...
```

**password-reset.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('password_reset')
export class PasswordEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  accessToken: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isExpired: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Is the isExpired really received as a boolean to the controller? Can you add a console log there?
`@Put('updateToken/:accessToken')
  updateExpiryStatus(
    @Param('accessToken') accessToken: string,
    @Body() isExpired: boolean
  ): Promise<string> {
    console.log(isExpired);
    return this.passwordService.updateExpiryStatus(accessToken, isExpired);
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you already query the `PasswordEntity` with this

```
const expiryStatus = await this.passwordRepository.findOne({
      where: { accessToken },
    });
```

Then you can do this to update the `isExpired`

```
expiryStatus.isExpired = isExpired;
await this.passwordRepository.save(expiryStatus);
```

This will update the status for the row that you fetch with the `accessToken`.

`this.passwordRepository.save(expiryStatus)` will return the newly updated row.